# The point about Bumblebee

Tags: bumblebee

As I assume, Bumblebee can automatically switch between graphic cards and you can force an application to use exact GPU (though you don't have to). The switch is to save power (as nVidia GPU is stronger but consumes more power).

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ):

> #### I have a laptop with Nvidia card and an integrated graphics card, how can Bumblebee help me?
>
> By disabling the nvidia card, power is saved. This improves battery life. If you need more graphical performance, Bumblebee can run the program using the Nvidia card.

So, yes.

Comment: But this all happens automatically?

Comment: @Jantomedes It does? How do you imagine that happens?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run the desired app with "optirun" or "primus" in front of it.

Example: optirun glxinfo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this apply to Ubuntu or not but don't forget to install bbswitch too. Last time I didn't this and my battery drain very fast.

Good luck